# Adding Łukasiewicz-style quantifiers over truth value (Σ, Π) to classical sentential logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

What kind of system results if you add quantifiers over truth values / truth-valued variables to classical sentential logic?

Does the kind of system that results have a name?

Is there a straightforward translation from classical sentenial logic + truth value quantifiers into a more well-known/common system that doesn't result in exponential blowup of the terms? (i.e. ruling out $Πc\varphi \mapsto \left(\varphi[c:=\bot] \; \land \; \varphi[c:=\top] \right)$ and $Σc\varphi \mapsto \left(\varphi[c:=\bot] \; \lor \; \varphi[c:=\top]\right)$) I'm assuming that, if such a translation exists, then classical logic + truth value quantifiers might be *just a curiosity* or a nonstandard notation for a subset of an existing thing.

[The  Wikipedia article on Polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation) gives two quantifiers Σ and Π, corresponding to the more familiar $\exists$ and $\forall$, respectively.

Here's an excerpt from the table explaining the mapping between conventional and Polish notation, $p$ is intended to range over variables and $\varphi$ is an arbitrary *wff*.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Operator} & \text{Polish Notation} & \text{Conventional Notation} \\
\hline
\text{Universal quantifier} & Πp\varphi & \forall p . \varphi \\
\text{Existential quantifier} & Σp\varphi & \exists p . \varphi \\
\hline
\end{array}

Since Łukasiewicz's notation is a notation for sentential logic which, traditionally, has no notion of individuals in a domain of discourse to be quantified over, the table helpfully has an explanation of what the quantifiers mean.

> Note that the quantifiers ranged over propositional values in
>   Łukasiewicz's work on many-valued logics.

This almost immediately strikes me as a generalization of tautology / satisfiability. Normally an expression like $P \land Q$ stands on its own and whether it's *supposed to be a tautology* or *supposed to be satisfiable* isn't surfaced in the notation and doesn't seem to be part of the intrinsic *meaning* of the expression.

However, Σ and Π can trivially be used to surface whether we want to consider the consider the resulting expression as a tautology or potentially satisfiable thing just by adding a prefix of $ΣaΣbΣc\cdots$ or $ΠaΠbΠc$ to bind the free variables in the matrix of the expression.

It's more general than just that, since $(Σa(a \land a)) \lor (ΠaΠb(a \lor b))$ is expressible.

Comment: [Quantified Propositional Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/quantification/#QuaProLog). See also [Quantified Propositional Logic](http://courseweb.stthomas.edu/kwkemp/logic/L/6QL/LL16QL1.pdf).

Comment: Lukasiewicz wrote in "Elements of Mathematical Logic": "The term "quantifier" was used by Peirce in his paper of 1885.  We shall first of all explain the meaning of the universal quantifier, symbolized by Peirce as Π".

Comment: You can say, for example, "The Law of the excluded middle implies double negation elimination", $$(\Pi ~P~.~P\lor \lnot P) \to (\Pi~ P~.~\lnot \lnot P \to P)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the appendix to his *Formal Logic* A. N. Prior calls systems with an implication connective and a universal quantifier over propositions, "Extended Propositional Calculus".